# When is an ellipsoidally (elliptical) distributed random variable spherically symmetric?

Tags: distributions, symmetry, exchangeability

If $Y$ is ellipsoidally distributed, and $\mu_y \propto 1_p$ and $\sum_y = \sigma^2 I$ is $Y$ spherically symmetric? EDIT: added - Is it exchangeably distributed? Please give a proof not a yes/no.

Comment: Why would you need $\mu_y \propto 1_p$?

Comment: yes this is the spherically symmetric case!

Comment: what do you mean by the spherically symmetric case? the multivariate normal is spherically symmetric but need satisfy neither of these cases? @Xi'an

Comment: Maybe you could start by stating what you mean by elliptically distributed. My understanding taken from Kelker (1970, Sankhyã) is that the density factorises as $$g((y-\mu_y)^T\Sigma_y^{-1}(y-\mu_y))$$. In the event when $\Sigma_y=\sigma^2 I_p$, this gives the special case of spherically symmetric distributions since $$||y-\mu_y||$$ is invariant by rotation.